# JVM crash with regard to Cannot allocate memory

Tags: java, wildfly, java-ee-7

I'm working on a java web-application deployed on wildfly that last night is crashed with the following errors:

```
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007fba27a7b000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
    #
    # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
    # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # /root/hs_err_pid4769.log
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
    Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
```

My hs_err_pid4769.log:

```
                ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

            OS:CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

            uname:Linux 2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 26 17:51:45 UTC 2018 x86_64
            libc:glibc 2.12 NPTL 2.12
            rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE 0k, NPROC 920092, NOFILE 65536, AS infinity
            load average:0.85 0.80 1.01

            /proc/meminfo:
            MemTotal:       235571916 kB
            MemFree:        97943452 kB
            Buffers:          271708 kB
            Cached:         51437016 kB
            SwapCached:            0 kB
            Active:         110257256 kB
            Inactive:       24390552 kB
            Active(anon):   82936048 kB
            Inactive(anon):     4916 kB
            Active(file):   27321208 kB
            Inactive(file): 24385636 kB
            Unevictable:           0 kB
            Mlocked:               0 kB
            SwapTotal:       4194300 kB
            SwapFree:        4194300 kB
            Dirty:              8700 kB
            Writeback:             0 kB
            AnonPages:      82939164 kB
            Mapped:           144656 kB
            Shmem:              1816 kB
            Slab:             742360 kB
            SReclaimable:     432904 kB
            SUnreclaim:       309456 kB
            KernelStack:      496752 kB
            PageTables:       232404 kB
            NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
            Bounce:                0 kB
            WritebackTmp:          0 kB
            CommitLimit:    121980256 kB
            Committed_AS:   116144276 kB
            VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
            VmallocUsed:      578872 kB
            VmallocChunk:   34139221212 kB
            HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
            AnonHugePages:  79087616 kB
            HugePages_Total:       0
            HugePages_Free:        0
            HugePages_Rsvd:        0
            HugePages_Surp:        0
            Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
            DirectMap4k:       10240 kB
            DirectMap2M:    239065088 kB


            CPU:total 24 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 62 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, tsc, tscinvbit

            /proc/cpuinfo:
            processor       : 0
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 0
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 0
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 0
            initial apicid  : 0
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 1
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 0
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 1
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 1
            initial apicid  : 1
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 2
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 1
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 0
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 2
            initial apicid  : 2
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 3
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 1
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 1
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 3
            initial apicid  : 3
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 4
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 2
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 0
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 4
            initial apicid  : 4
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 5
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 2
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 1
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 5
            initial apicid  : 5
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 6
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 3
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 0
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 6
            initial apicid  : 6
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 7
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 3
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 1
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 7
            initial apicid  : 7
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 8
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 4
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 0
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 8
            initial apicid  : 8
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 9
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 4
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 1
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 9
            initial apicid  : 9
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 10
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 5
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 0
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 10
            initial apicid  : 10
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 11
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 5
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 1
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 11
            initial apicid  : 11
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 12
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 6
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 0
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 12
            initial apicid  : 12
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 13
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 6
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 1
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 13
            initial apicid  : 13
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 14
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 7
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 0
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 14
            initial apicid  : 14
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 15
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 7
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 1
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 15
            initial apicid  : 15
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 16
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 8
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 0
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 16
            initial apicid  : 16
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 17
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 8
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 1
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 17
            initial apicid  : 17
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 18
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 9
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 0
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 18
            initial apicid  : 18
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 19
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 9
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 1
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 19
            initial apicid  : 19
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 20
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 10
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 0
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 20
            initial apicid  : 20
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 21
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 10
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 1
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 21
            initial apicid  : 21
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 22
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 11
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 0
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 22
            initial apicid  : 22
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:

            processor       : 23
            vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
            cpu family      : 6
            model           : 62
            model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v2 @ 3.30GHz
            stepping        : 4
            microcode       : 1064
            cpu MHz         : 3300.000
            cache size      : 25600 KB
            physical id     : 11
            siblings        : 2
            core id         : 1
            cpu cores       : 2
            apicid          : 23
            initial apicid  : 23
            fpu             : yes
            fpu_exception   : yes
            cpuid level     : 13
            wp              : yes
            flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm arat
            bogomips        : 6600.00
            clflush size    : 64
            cache_alignment : 64
            address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
            power management:



            Memory: 4k page, physical 235571916k(97943452k free), swap 4194300k(4194300k free)

            vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.91-b14) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_91-b14), built on Apr  1 2016 00:57:21 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

            time: Thu Aug 13 01:55:32 2020
            elapsed time: 44307 seconds (0d 12h 18m 27s)
```

Any suggestion about this?

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that the JVM has asked the operating system for more memory for something, and the operating system has said No.  You might have attempted to exceed the process (or container) limits, or you may have used all of the system's allocatable virtual memory.

It is unclear what the JVM was requesting memory for, but it could have been the stack segments for a thread that it is starting.

I would check that:

- you are not creating too many threads,
- you are not using some native code library that is leaking native heap memory.